# When does a function on the circle have a finite Dirichlet energy extension to the disk?

Tags: analysis, potential-theory

It is often stated that the Dirichlet problem on a domain (say a disk in the plane) can be solved by finding the extension of the boundary data with minimal Dirichlet energy.

However, this obviously only makes sense if there is an extension of finite energy to begin with. You can find an example, due to Hadamard, where this is not the case [in these notes (page 9).](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f13/dirichlet.pdf)

Are there any good conditions on the boundary function to ensure that this is the case? For example, do the following classes of functions have finite energy extensions: smooth (yes), Lipschitz, Holder...? What about something like Brownian motion?

Alternatively, are there any standard `candidate functions' that tend to give good bounds for the energy?

For example, we could take the homogenous extension $u(rz)=r^{\alpha}f(z)$
and [one can show](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154133/dirichlet-energy-of-a-harmonic-function-bounded-above-by-the-energy-of-the-bound)   that the dirichlet energy of this extension is bounded by the energy of the boundary data.
This is far too weak to answer my question for Brownian boundary data though.

Comment: Are you fixing a domain which is topologically nice, and just asking about regularity of the boundary function on that domain?

Comment: Yes, I only care about nice domains such as disk or half plane. Concrete question: Let $f(e^{2\pi it}) = B_t-t B_1$ where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion on $[0,1]$. Does $f$ have a finite energy extension to the disk?

Comment: I think this might be a hard enough question that you should ask it over on Overflow instead.